# Orientation of a texture image in Cesium?

Tags: cesium, texture, 3d-orientation

#### Context

I'm trying to apply a texture to an entity in [CesiumJS](https://cesium.com/) and I cannot figure out how the texture is applied, especially regarding it's orientation relative to the camera view point.

Here are two result examples of a texture image applied to an entity that I have constructed from a [Cesium.GeoJsonDataSource](https://cesium.com/docs/cesiumjs-ref-doc/GeoJsonDataSource.html).

The camera position and 3D orientation is roughly the same in both cases.
The only difference is in the shape of the polygon.

On the left image the texture is applied on this shape:

```
  [ 10.746038315853207, 48.314905418639555, 500 ], 
  [ 10.747038310965864, 48.315905422444722, 500 ], 
  [ 10.747500009924019, 48.315700009648104, 550 ], 
  [ 10.746500009923748, 48.314700009648320, 550 ], 
  [ 10.746038315853207, 48.314905418639555, 500 ]
```

and on the right image the texture is applied on this shape (the two lower points in altitude become the two higher and vice-versa):

```
  [ 10.746038315853207, 48.314905418639555, 550 ],
  [ 10.747038310965864, 48.315905422444722, 550 ],
  [ 10.747500009924019, 48.315700009648104, 500 ],
  [ 10.746500009923748, 48.314700009648320, 500 ],
  [ 10.746038315853207, 48.314905418639555, 550 ]
```

Notice that only the altitudes are swapped (lower values became higher and vice-versa, for each node, which keep their (lon,lat) values the same.)

[image: examples of different orientation of a texture image on a polygon entity]

The texture is applied as this in both cases:

```js
entity.polygon.material = new Cesium.ImageMaterialProperty({
  image: 'Cesium3DTiles.jpg',
  alpha: 0.5
});
```

#### Question

I wonder what exactly defines the orientation of a texture image applied onto an entity in Cesium?

And more importantly, how can I display the texture image in a way which always let the text readable, relative to the (fixed) camera viewpoint orientation?

I'm using CesiumJS 1.73